# Searching from the latest date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following scenario :For id = 2 the run date starts from 2015-01-30 to 2014-11-28 as per the database records since i am searching for last 3 months record and then trying to get the difference between x month - latest data point value which is 11(VALUE AT 2015-01-30) -5 (VALUE AT 2014-11-28)= 6 for id =2 . But i want to modify my query such that it starts from 1 month back from today and takes the first date of that month(i.e 1 feb 2015 :1st date of every month) even though the first data point in the database records starts from 2015-01-30 the actual search should start from 1feb 2015  in which the difference should be 8 - 0 = 8 rather than 6 . How can tweak my query to do this

The goal is to find the deviation between two values :the value at x month back - the latest value .So for id 2 since there is no feb data available in the datatable (whic represents the temp table) the latest value becomes 0 and the x month back value becomes 8 ( value in dec-2014) = 8- 0  = 8

```
CREATE TABLE #t ( ID INT, V FLOAT, D DATE )

INSERT  INTO #t
VALUES  ( 1, 1.2, '2014-01-01' ),
        ( 1, 1.33, '2014-01-02' ),
        ( 1, 1.33, '2014-01-03' ),
        ( 2, 7, '2014-10-31' ),
        ( 2, 5, '2014-11-28' ),
        ( 2, 8, '2014-12-31' ),
        ( 2, 11, '2015-01-30' );

DECLARE @DealClauseString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DealClauseString = ';WITH    filter
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        D ,
                        V ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D DESC ) AS RN
               FROM     #t 
             ),
        cte
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        D ,
                        V ,
                        MIN(D) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D ROWS 
                                      BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                      AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS Min ,
                        MAX(D) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D ROWS 
                                      BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
                                      UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS Max
               FROM     filter
              WHERE    RN <= 2
             )
    SELECT  c1.ID ,
            c2.V - c1.V AS V
    FROM    cte c1
            JOIN cte c2 ON c1.ID = c2.ID AND c1.D < c2.D
    WHERE   ( c1.D = c1.MIN OR c1.D = c1.MAX ) 
            AND ( c2.D = c2.MIN OR c2.D = c2.MAX ) and c2.V - c1.V between 0.3 and 6 '
EXEC (@DealClauseString)
    drop table      #t
```

Any help would be really helfull.Pleasse let me know if you have any queries

Comment: I've read your description three times and still can't make any sense of it.  Can you clarify?  How are you getting 6 for ID = 2?

Comment: @amoodys . . . Sample data and desired results are often very useful for explaining what code is supposed to do.

Comment: Hopefully i added more information to my actual query to make  my output more clear